# ClassNotFoundException for different packages com.tencent.mmkv.MMKV and com.transsion.hubsdk.os.TranBuild

Tags: android, exception

I'm trying to open activity on button click but app is crashing with these 2 different exceptions.
Note: com.tencent.mmkv.MMKV and com.transsion.hubsdk.os.TranBuild are not project packages
Here's are 2 logcats of different package crashes having different package names.

```
init mmkv error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:       com.tencent.mmkv.MMKV at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
  - at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
  - at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:379)
  - at c4.a.(source.java:2)
  - at c4.a.(Unknown Source:2)
  - at com.cloud.sdk.commonutil.util.DeviceUtil.e(source.java:2)
  - at com.cloud.hisavana.sdk.api.config.AdManager.b(Unknown Source:62)
  - at com.cloud.hisavana.sdk.api.config.AdManager.c(Unknown Source:6)
  - at com.hisavana.adxlibrary.check.ExistsCheck.init(source.java:4)
  - at wc.a.a(source.java:14)
  - at wc.a.f(source.java:2)
  - at com.hisavana.mediation.config.TAdManager.c(Unknown Source:10)
  - at com.hisavana.mediation.config.TAdManager.e(source.java:11)
  - at com.hisavana.mediation.config.TAdManager.init(source.java:3)
  - at xg.d.h(source.java:16)
  - at com.cyin.himgr.ads.AdManager.initSdk(source.java:2)
  - at com.cyin.himgr.ads.AdUtils.initADSDK(source.java:8)
  - at com.transsion.common.MainApplication.l(Unknown Source:8)
  - at com.transsion.common.MainApplication.onCreate(source.java:19)
  - at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1198)
  - at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7038)
  - at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:257)
  - at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2025)
  - at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
  - at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:268)
  - at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8004)
  - at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  - at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:627)
  - at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:997)
  - 
  - 
  - 
  - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.transsion.hubsdk.os.TranBuild
  - at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
  - at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
  - at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:379)
  - at com.transsion.hubsdk.common.reflect.TranDoorMan.getFieldString(TranDoorMan.java:1)
  - at com.transsion.hubsdk.common.version.TranVersion.(TranVersion.java:2)
  - at com.transsion.hubsdk.common.version.TranVersion$Core.(TranVersion.java:1)
  - at com.transsion.hubsdk.common.verifykey.TranVerifyKeyManager.verify(TranVerifyKeyManager.java:1)
  - at com.transsion.hubsdk.TranHubSdkManager.init(TranHubSdkManager.java:2)
  - at yi.b.e(AppInitiater.java:6)
  - at com.transsion.magicmovie.application.VideoApplication.onCreate(VideoApplication.java:3)
  - at com.transsion.magicshow.application.VideoPlayerApplication.onCreate(VideoPlayerApplication.java:3)
  - at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1198)
  - at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7038)
  - at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:257)
  - at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2025)
  - at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
  - at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:268)
  - at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8004)
  - at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  - at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:627)
  - at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:997)
```

How can I fix these crashes? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.